# Subset notation with multiple conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $A = \{k : k\in\Bbb Z^+, 1\le k\le p\}$.
Let
\begin{align}
B &= \{k \in A: \text{$k$ is prime}\}\\
C &= \{k \in A: \text{$k$ is composite}\}\\
D &= \{(k, k+2): k \in A\}
\end{align}

I want to create $E$ with the condition: those number pairs in $B$, where $k$ is prime, and $k+2$ is composite, and I also want to show that $E$ is a subset of $D$.

For example if $p=5$, then
$$A=\{1,2,3,4,5\},\ B=\{2,3,5\},\ C=\{4\},\ D=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,7)\}$$
Then $E=\{(2,4)\}$.

Can I just simply say $E \subset D = \{(k,k+2) \in D: k \in B \text{ and } k+2 \in C\}$, or if not, how should I formulate what is $E$?

Comment: You have changed the definition of $D$ in the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have$$\begin{cases}B_p=\{k:1\le k\le p, k\text{ prime}\}\\C_p=\{k:1\le k\le p, k\text{ composite}\}=\{k:3\le k\le p, k\text{ composite}\}\\D_p=\{(k,k+2):1\le k\le p\}\end{cases}$$You want to select those numbers $k\in B_p$ such that $k+2$ is composite. Note that $1\le k\le p\Leftrightarrow 3\le k+2\le p+2$, so  $k+2\in C_{p+2}$.

So $(k,k+2)\in B_p\times C_{p+2}$. But $B_p\times C_{p+2}$ contains many extraneous elements not of the form $(k,k+2)$. So we take the intersection with $D_p$ to remove all pairs that are not of the form $(k,k+2)$. Thus your required set is$$E_p=B_p\times C_{p+2}\cap D_p$$From here, it is apparent that $E\subseteq D_p$. Also note that $(1,3)\in D_p\forall p$ but $(1,3)\notin E_p$  and thus $E\subset D_p$.